# Cannot get template on jinja2

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm trying to use `jinja2` as template for a xml-like language.

The code below, is a example of this language with a jinja2 base template. This template calls a child one.

**Base Template:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!-- An NCL SlideShow example with embedded Jinja2 template -->
<ncl id="slideShow">
    <head>
        <connectorBase>
            <importBase documentURI="connectorBase.ncl" alias="conBase"/>
        </connectorBase>
        <regionBase>
            <region id="main" width="100%" height="100%" zIndex="1"/>
        </regionBase>
        <descriptorBase>
            <descriptor id="ImageDes" region="main"/>
        </descriptorBase>
    </head>
    <body>
        <port id="startSlideShow" component="image1"/>
        {% block medias %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</ncl>
```

**Child Template:**

```
{% extends "slide_show.j2.ncl" %}
{% block media %}
    <media id="image1" src="media/WinterSun.jpg" 
descriptor="ImageDes"/> 
{% endblock media %}
```

From a python code, I try to load base template file.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = Environment(
        loader=FileSystemLoader('/templates/slide_show.j2'),
        autoescape=select_autoescape(['ncl', 'xml'])
    )

    template = env.get_template('slide_show.j2')
```

However, I get this exception below:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: slide_show.j2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that `FyleSystemLoader` should receives full path to folder, not a relative. Their documentation doesn't make it clear.

```
loader = FileSystemLoader('fullpath/to/file')
```